# DocuSign REST API with radio button group tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently generating DocuSign envelopes using DocuSign REST API. I have included a lot of tags and everything seems to be working fine.

I have included radio button group tabs for the same document. For some reason, after I include certain number of radio button group tab, I am getting a strange error. So far, I have added close to 80 radio button groups. Each group have YES/NO - two or more radio buttons. I have setup the value, selected properties of the radio group/radio the same way as other radio button group tab.

Here are the error details:

CUSTOMTAB_IS_INCOMPLETE
A custom tab is not complete. A custom tab requires both a name and a tab label. Radio tabs may only have one radio selected in a group.

The properties of all the radio buttons/radio groups are setup the same way.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Minal

Comment: Would you be able to provide an API log of your envelope creation call with any PII/Proprietary data removed?

Comment: Also can you provide the Corresponding JSON for REST call?

Answer (score 1):

There is a provision for creating a custom tab. But in the case of a custom tab, both the attributes Name and TabLabel should be specified. If only one of the attribute is specified in the Tab element then an exception

> CUSTOMTAB_IS_INCOMPLETE

is thrown.